# Using OR within regex pattern of grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I use the following pattern for regex match in grep (zgrep, as searching within compressed files) as

```
zgrep -P '(?<=start).{20,120}(?=end)' *
```

I need to add some terms with `OR` operator in the middle, but this pattern does not work

```
zgrep -P '(?<=start)[first|second|third].{20,120}(?=end)' *
```

How can I introduce `first|second|third` in the middle of the matching string?

Comment: @jimmij wonderful. So silly of me. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it. Maybe helping someone else, as I couldn't find by searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression in brackets `[..]` matches any single character from the list, so `[first|second|third]` matches each letter separately: `f`, `i`, `r`, `s`, `t`, `|`, `e`, etc. (notice no need of second `s`). There are few exceptions from that rule like `^` at the beginning is negation or `-` marks character range, but the pipe `|` is not special so `grep` just searches for this sign in the file.

What you want is `(first|second|third)`. Everything inside `(..)` forms a sub-expression of main regular expression and can be combined/joined with `|` which is interpreted as OR operator.